# Jelastic Enforce SSL on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, jelastic

I'm trying to enforce the SSL protocol in a Jelastic Enviroment.
My setup is:

- one node, with a Nginx Load balancer (+ public ip + custom ssl certificate) and a NodeJS application server.

The SSL setup is working, but i want to enforce the use of HTTPS no HTTP (a redirect).

I've tried to modify the nginx.conf but no success.

Any ideas how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the config file /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx_force_https.conf and add the lines below:

```
server {
    listen 80;       
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

It will redirect all configured sites to https.

If you want only exact site example.com:

```
server {   
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Make sure that you have these includes enabled in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
include /etc/nginx/nginx-jelastic.conf;
```

in /etc/nginx/nginx-jelastic.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Check for errors in the configuration:

```
sudo service nginx configtest
```

Reload configuration (this would be enough to make changes "work"):

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Check if all works as expected. Restart the whole webserver (if needed):

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

The detailed answer can be found in this post [Force www. and https in nginx.conf (SSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486739/force-www-and-https-in-nginx-conf-ssl/36777526#36777526)